# Applying style to ASP.NET RadioButtonList

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to style RadioButtonList in ASP.NET just like this:

[image: Radio Buttons]

This can be found here [FlatUI link](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/)

I noticed that the FlatUI radio buttons are formatted like this:

[image]

But when I give a class to RadioButtonList, I am not getting desired output.

My markup is this

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="WTRBTNList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="WTRBTNList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="radio">
                            <asp:ListItem  Text="Pending Tests" Value="Pending" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Approved Tests" Value="Approved"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Rejected Tests" Value="Rejected"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </div>
         <div class="col-lg-7">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? What am I missing here?

Comment: As someone who's a front-end developer and worked with .NET, I would suggest ditching any `<asp>` tags to create form elements, _especially_ the checkbox/radio lists. Just simply create the HTML you want yourself, rather than relying on .NET to render something for you that's as helpful as a chocolate teapot.

Comment: @JamieBarker thanks... that sounds good... But on change of radio button selection, .NET makes a postback. If I use plain html, how would i have that functionality ?

Comment: JavaScript/jQuery. You have the jQuery tag so I'll give you a jQuery example: `$('input[type="radio"]).on('change', function() { $(this).closest('form').submit(); });`. That will take all radio buttons and submit the closest form to them, or rather the form they are nested inside, when they are changed.

Comment: Let me try that ... will get back to you... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Also here's a [helpful article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953) for styling those Radio buttons using just CSS.

Comment: Hello @JamieBarker, thanks that helped. The form is making a postback now. But after the postback, it does not select the radio button that I selected i.e. the new selection. It is still showing the old selected radio button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86661/discussion-between-athar-anis-and-jamie-barker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comment, you should ditch the awful .NET `<asp>` tags for inputs and use native code, especially for radio and checkbox lists.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
         <input type="radio" name="tests" value="Pending"<%If Reqeust.Form("tests") = "Pending" Then%> checked="checked"<%End If%> /><label>Pending</label>
         <input type="radio" name="tests" value="Pending"<%If Reqeust.Form("tests") = "Approved" Then%> checked="checked"<%End If%> /><label>Approved</label>
         <input type="radio" name="tests" value="Pending"<%If Reqeust.Form("tests") = "Rejected" Then%> checked="checked"<%End If%> /><label>Rejected</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then if you want to keep the form posting when the radio is clicked, use the following jQuery:

```
$('input[type="radio"]).on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Then if you want to style your radio button, you can read this [helpful article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953) which uses the `:checked` pseudo selector:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label { }
```

Comment: very well explained....in case these radio button are in UpdatePanel, i used this   __doPostBack('MainContent_UpdatePanel1', '');